# Abp framework - How do you add a language? change it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, abp

Suppose I want to add Hebrew as a supported language and ensure that it is displayed in a right-to-left (RTL) format, like Arabic. How can I achieve this(and make it the default)?

Additionally, when creating a simple CRUD page on the UI, the text for the "Actions" button is preset depending on the language. However, this text does not exist in the code or any other relevant location. I have attempted to search for the word throughout the entire solution, but it cannot be found. Here is the relevant code:

```
 <DataGridEntityActionsColumn TItem="ReportDTO" @ref="@EntityActionsColumn">
        <DisplayTemplate>
            <EntityActions TItem="ReportDTO" EntityActionsColumn="@EntityActionsColumn">
                <EntityAction TItem="ReportDTO"
                              Text="@L["Edit"]"
                              Clicked="() => OpenEditModalAsync(context)" />
                <EntityAction TItem="ReportDTO"
                              Text="@L["Delete"]"
                              Clicked="() => DeleteEntityAsync(context)"
                              ConfirmationMessage="() => GetDeleteConfirmationMessage(context)" />
            </EntityActions>
        </DisplayTemplate>
    </DataGridEntityActionsColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your template option? Blazor, MVC or angular?

Did you read docs ? https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Localization
There is a section add new localization.

Comment: How can you translate the administration module?

Comment: Every module has own json file. https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.UI/Localization/Resources/AbpUi/en.json
 
Administration is a just a group name. You can edit en.json one by one.

Comment: thanks for replying.. Using blazor server, where would i find the module specific json files in the project itself? try looking everywhere but cant seem to locate, neither the blazor one, or the administration one, can you point me in the right direction? the only translation files i see contain just basic text  for the welcome screen ,nothing to do with the modules etc